# what hardware can I use to connect a Laserdisc player to my laptop?

Tags: video

I have a Windows 7 Laptop (Sony VGN-Z12GN) and a Pioneer DVL-9 Laserdisc player.

I want to digitize some of my Laserdiscs.

I have some experience with video transcoding (Virtual Dub, Sony Vegas), but I have absolutely no idea how I to get the signal from the Laserdisc player into the laptop in the first place.

What kind of hardware is necessary and most useful for this purpose?

I somewhere read that I can use a TV card for this, but as I described above, I have a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The best quality output that your LaserDisc player has is S-Video, so you will want to get a capture device that supports S-Video input.

Your laptop has three inputs that could be used.  You have 4 pin firewire, ExpressCard34 and USB2.0.  The USB solutions are the cheapest, but also generally the lowest quality.  Either a firewire based external adapter or an ExpressCard34 internal adapter should work about equally well depending on build quality.  The data rates supported are much higher and the quality should be superior, but it's also going to cost more as that moves more into prosumer and professional territory.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you much in terms of capture devices.  Most of the tech has moved on to being HD focused at this point and finding products that are still made to capture high quality SD video seems to be trickier now than it used to be.

Comment: Thank you. Just a note: Laserdisc contains an analog, composite signal. The S-Video on the DVL-9 is only included because the DVL-9 can also play DVDs. So I think composite to firewire or composite to ExpressCard34 should be sufficient from what I understand.

Comment: The DVL-9 *may* have a high quality composite decoding system, so I wouldn't completely give up on S-Video. You won't really know until you try it, and S-Video input shouldn't increase your cost much.